# Bash Script to HTML has Annoying Character

Tags: bash, shell-script

Hello I am running a bash shell script to send to html page but the html page keeps putting this "[7l" character in with my shell command output from the bash script.

```
echo "<pre>"                                                 >> stats.html
echo "####### DISK Usage  ########" >> stats.html
/usr/bin/dstat --disk-util --disk --top-bio-adv 1 1   >> stats.html
echo "</pre>"                                                 >> stats.html
```

And the html page has this in it

```
####### DISK Usage  ########
[7lsda- -dsk/total- ----most-expensive-block-i/o-process----
util| read  writ|process              pid  read write cpu
0.04|  16k 8087B|systemd              1    8111B6247B0.0%
```

Comment: Have you tried the `--nocolor` option?

Comment: That's not a color-code (looks like someone hard-coded something to attempt to ignore wrapping without bothering to notice that output's redirected).

Answer (score 3):

Just filter the thing:

```
/usr/bin/dstat ... | sed 's/\x1b\[7l//' >> stats.html
```

Since `dstat` is a python script, you can also fix it by just editing it: take the `sys.stdout.write` line after the `### Disable line wrapping` and move it (properly indented) after the `if sys.stdout.isatty()`:

```
--- dstat~
+++ dstat
@@ -2267,10 +2267,10 @@
     hostname = os.uname()[1]

     ### Disable line-wrapping (does not work ?)
-    sys.stdout.write('\033[7l')

     ### Write term-title
     if sys.stdout.isatty():
+        sys.stdout.write('\033[7l')
         shell = os.getenv('XTERM_SHELL')
         term = os.getenv('TERM')
         if shell == '/bin/bash' and term and re.compile('(screen*|xterm*)').match(term):
```

Comment: The sed command helped thanks.

Comment: @AndreasMagana Good! If this solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers